# How do I use javascript to update the values of hidden input fields

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following fields:

```
First Name: <input type="text" id="tFName" name="tFName" maxlength="50" />
Last Name:  <input type="text" id="tLName" name="tLName" maxlength="50" />
```

I want to use javaScript specifically dojo to update the value of the following hidden input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tFName" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="tLName" value=""/>
```

what are some ways in Javascript and Dojo to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we modify the html some (setting an ID on the hidden ones) we can:

```
First Name: <input type="text" id="tFName" name="tFName" maxlength="50" />
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenFName" name="tFName" value=""/>


var fName = dijit.byId("tFName");
var hFName = dijit.byId("hiddenFName");

hFName.attr("value", fName.attr("value"));
```

Comment: If some of these is a <select>, this won't work. val() is much better.

Answer (score 5):

```
dojo.query('#tFName').val('Joe');
```

See the [val() docs](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/HEAD/dojo.NodeList.val).

Comment: Just remember to add `dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate");` or this will not work.

Answer (score 3):

In plain Javascript, you can just set the `.value` property:

```
document.<form name>.tFName.value = <whatever>
document.<form name>.tLName.value = <whatever>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: document.getElementsByName("tFName")[0].value ="abc";
          document.getElementsByName("tLName")[0].value ="def";