# How to access an HTML textbox from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

How to access an HTML textbox by a javascript function?

Comment: Do you mean, to get the value of the text box?

Comment: yes exactly. without going back to the server though

Comment: [More ways in earlier thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206336/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-update-the-values-of-hidden-input-fields/4206459#4206459)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set ID property on text box and use document.getElementById() function... Example below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doSomethingWithTextBox()
{
  var textBox = document.getElementById('TEXTBOX_ID');
  // do something with it ...

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="TEXTBOX_ID">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For conciseness, this would not actually get the value of the textbox (TEXTBOX_ID) unless you called the function doSomethingWithTextBox(). You would need to call the function doSomethingWithTextBox() after your input tag (TEXTBOX_ID) otherwise doSomethingWithTextBox() would be looking for a textbox that does not yet exist, and you;d get an error.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to be able to get a DOM(Document Object Model) reference to the textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" value="Hello World!" />
```

Notice the `id` attribute, the textbox now has the id `mytextbox`.

Next step is to get the reference in JavaScript:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('mytextbox'); // assign the DOM element reference to the variable "textbox"
```

This will retrieve a HTML Element by its `id` attribute. Note that those id's need to be unique, so you can't have two textboxes with the same id.

Now the final step is to retrieve the value of the textbox:

```
alert(textbox.value); // alert the contents of the textbox to the user
```

The `value` property contains the contents of the textbox, and that's it!

For more reference you might want to check out some stuff over at MDC:
[GetElementByID Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById)
[Input Element Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement)
[A general overview of the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/About_the_Document_Object_Model)

Answer (score 6):

Very simply, try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        …
    </head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="textbox" type="text" />
    </form>
    <script>
        var textboxValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    </script>
</body>
```

The variable `textboxValue` would equal whatever you've typed into the textbox.

Remember you must place your script, if written as simply as this, after the textbox (`input` field) appears in your HTML, otherwise when the page first loads you'd get an error, because the script is looking for `input` field that has not yet been created by the browser.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Give your textbox an `id` attribute, and after, fetch it with `document.getElementById('<textbox id>')`.

Answer (score 4):

document.getElementById('textboxid').value
   or
document.formname.textboxname.value